# Can I parry projectiles?

Tags: furi

I can parry to block damage from bosses' melee attacks. Can I also parry as a projectile hits me to cancel its damage? If so, do I gain health like I do when parrying a melee attack, or does it only prevent damage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can parry projectiles. A comment in the thread [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Furi/comments/4wqwpa/two_questions_about_gameplay_mechanics/) explains how:

> You [parry] projectiles the same way you parry regular attacks: Just hit the parry button right before it hits you.

It seems that parrying will reflect/deflect bullets, based on this [short Q&A](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/182190-furi/74004260). There is no mention of health absorption.